Genesis how to add a wallet?
{
"alloc": {
"0xe2138366adc7bae0b41d205e7d0ba8fadadd8e33": {
"balance": "99999999999999999"
}
},
"config": {
"chainId": 15,
"homesteadBlock": 0,
"eip155Block": 0,
"eip158Block": 0
},
"coinbase": "0xe2138366adc7bae0b41d205e7d0ba8fadadd8e33",
"difficulty": "0x20000",
"extraData": "","gasLimit":"0x2fefd8",
"nonce":"0x000000000001fd4e",
"mixhash":
"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
"parentHash":
"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
"timestamp":"0x00"
}

Have you tried adding another address inside "alloc"? Also, which client are you using (geth, ...) ?
